# Nohup process missing or killed after logging back in

Tags: unix, nohup

I need to run a java program on my university servers. I'm remotely logging in through their servers via ssh

So I used `nohup` like:

```
$ nohup java -jar project.jar &
```

However when I logout and close the terminal then log back into the server my process is missing/got killed off.

Comment: My mistake. If I use the top command I can see the process still running. However if I use the ps command, I'm not able to see it why is that?

Answer (score 1):

> If I use the top command I can see the process still running. However
>   if I use the ps command, I'm not able to see it why is that?

It is probably because you haven't passed an option to select that process, since by default, `ps` selects only processes associated with the same terminal as the invoker. Try

```
ps -u$USER
```